# Maven does not pick up war dependency in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi module Maven project. Parent project and then two other modules, one of which builds the war through its pom.xml.

```
Parent Project
 ---- Java Project
 ---- War Project
```

I build the war from parent project. There is another external war dependency in War project's pom.xml. Jars in that project are needed to build a specific profile, which is specified in War project's pom.xml. Maven cannot get those jars from war dependency. I ran the following command

```
mvn install:install <information about war>
```

to put it in local.m2 repository, but Maven doesn't pick anything from that dependency. I understand that Maven processes war dependencies differently than it does a jar dependency but I am unable to understand as to how will it pick it up? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit

This is how I try to include the war dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-id-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

Also, I would like to mention that I use that maven war dependency in `<overlay>` tag.

Comment: How are you depending on that war?  Maven defaults to jar's, unless you specify something else with `type`.

Comment: Hello @john16384 I edited the question to show the way I am adding that dependency.

Comment: If you are using the war in overlay the resulting war will contain everything except you have excluded something...So what is the problem?

Comment: @khmarbaise the dependent war is needed to compile the code.. and I keep getting errors regarding jars which should come from the dependent war. How do I make jars inside war's WEB-INF/lib folder available to compile the code and use it in overlay as well?

Comment: The original project should create a separate jar file which can be configured in maven-war-plugin via attach..something need to check the docs...